# Setting the Context Menu CenterInWindow dynamically in C++Builder

Tags: c++builder

The VCL components in C++Builder have a context menu: Postion | Align | Horizontal | CenterInWindow; I am creating VCL components dynamically at run time. How can I set this menu dynamically using code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't invoke that menu item, as it doesn't exist at runtime.  It is a feature of the IDE's Form Designer.

All you can do at runtime is set each control's `Left`/`Top` properties as needed, ie:

```cpp
Control = new TWhatever(...);
Control->Parent = ...;
Control->Left = (Control->Parent->Width - Control->Width) / 2;
Control->Height = (Control->Parent->Height - Control->Hieght) / 2;
```

Adjust as needed if you need to position multiple controls.